# Subqueries in linq instead of recursion

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a nested structure.

Class Page have ChildPages

```
class Page
{
 IQueryable<Page> ChildPages;
 string type; //catalog or product
}
```

I need get I should get a request for a sample of all products **(type=="product")** in all subcategories **(type=="catalog")**.

it is easy to do with loops and recursion. but it takes a lot of time and resources

Comment: You've used the words, "Page", "ChildPage", "Product", "Catalog", and "Subcategories" to describe one relationship, so I confess I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Your question needs a little "refactoring" to make it more clear.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this without recursion or loops.  How else are you going to get all descendant child pages at whatever depths they are at?

Comment: I update my post. I hope both will be clearer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is supported in EF, but you can use a recursive CTE query to retrieve the entire tree in one database call.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do recursive Linq is to use a Fixpoint operator (see below)

But I doubt EF will be able to convert this to a CTE query ( see @erikkallen answer ),  which is the only way I know to do recursive query in one statement.

```
class Page
{
    IQueryable<Page> ChildPages;
    string type; //catalog or product

    // the query
    static IQueryable<Page> GetProductsWithCatalogAncestor(IQueryable<Page> pages)
    {
        return FixPoint<bool, IQueryable<Page>, IQueryable<Page>>
            (processChildPages => (hasCatalogAncestor, thePages) 
                => thePages.SelectMany(p => (hasCatalogAncestor && p.type == "product" ) 
                    ? new[] { p }.AsQueryable()
                    : processChildPages(hasCatalogAncestor || p.type == "catalog", p.ChildPages)))
                    (false, pages);
    }

    // Generic FixPoint operator
    static Func<T1, T2, TResult> FixPoint<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<Func<T1, T2, TResult>, Func<T1, T2, TResult>> f)
    {
        return (t1, t2) => f(FixPoint(f))(t1, t2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `SelectMany()` to flatten the hierarchy.

```
var data = pages.SelectMany(p=>p.ChildPages)
                .Where(p=>p.type == "product" || p.type == "catalog");
```